# Catalog URL Rewrites Index process is working now. Please try run this process later

Tags: magento-1.9

Catalog URL Rewrites Index process is working now.

Please try run this process later.

While i do index management this is the error i am getting

What i have tried

- Give 777 permission to var/locks folders
- Delete all file of var/locks folder.
- migrated to another database

But still *i cant solve the problem*. 
How to resolve this issue? its almost 3 days

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I have problems with indexing from the admin panel I try indexing using SSH.

So if you have SSH-Access please use the following codes:

## reindex all indexes

```
php -f /shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

## reindex specific index

example:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute

catalog_product_attribute     Product Attributes
catalog_product_price         Product Prices
catalog_url                   Catalog Url Rewrites
catalog_product_flat          Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat         Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product      Category Product
catalogsearch_fulltext        Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock        Stock status
```

Comment: I tried to do but it show Could not open input file: indexer.php

Comment: its in the folder your-root/shell. run the codes from there!

Comment: Thank you it works but. When i give one more time from backend its processing.. What might be the issue. How to resolve completely

Comment: Just a clue but it seems to me that the indexing process itself takes longer than your php max_execution_time or you running out of memory. Any additional error messages in var/report or var/log that can help point out the problem?

Comment: I dont find any error logs related to that.. How to increase the memory .

Comment: Unfortunately SSH is where I'm getting the same error as OP. 
`bash-4.2$ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price`
`Product Prices Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.`

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex it programmatically :
1.Create a file on your magento root dir and run it to reindex Catalog URL Rewrites.

```
<?php 
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_url');
$process->reindexAll();
$process->reindexAll();

?>
```

Or See below for a better way to reindex each index:

```
<?php 
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
/* @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection */
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */
    $index->reindexAll();
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried this also not working

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento 1.9.1.0 database locks are used by default. Those locks can only be released by the thread which obtained them or by killing that thread. 
This is a workaround to be able to index anyway:

1) Execute in SSH, in Magento root dir

```
mkdir -p var/locks; rm -f var/locks/*
```

2) Create a new PHP file in your `shell` dir containing:

```
<?php
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_flat');
$process->setData('use_file_lock',1); // force file lock
$process->reindexAll();
```

3) Execute the PHP script you created in your `shell` dir.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure does it help you or not but It solved out my issue. I was crossed the same issue in one of the Magento setup. I followed below steps and it resolved my issue of catalog URL index stuck.

Steps which I followed:

1. Try to truncate table **core_url_rewrite** from database.
2. Remove files from **var/locks** folder that created on Magento root directory.
3. if you have SSH then try to run indexing one by one using indexer for more info check this link [https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line](https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/)/
4. If you don't have SSH info then try to run create a PHP script which will do indexing for you as @Jeroen Vermeulen BVBA suggested.

For more help check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470855/magento-re-indexing-issue) Hope that will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the /var/locks folder has 777 permission and the locks files have 666 permission.

Still, not working?. Clear /var/locks files and try to reindex from SSH with below syntax:

Before proceeding just clear all the lock files under /var/locks

php shell/indexer.php -reindexall

Reindexing from code level:

Before proceeding just clear all the lock files under /var/locks

https://makandracards.com/magento/10687-reindex-via-code

If the code throws the error just increase the server max_execution_time.

This works for me!!!!